# Elements of a component aren't taking up 100% of the page's width

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

### UPDATE | found the reason to this:

If you put the `<router-view>` in a `<main>` tag this will happen.

---

### Question

I'm not sure if that's how it supposed to work.

But the component isn't taking 100% of the page width. Do you always have to specify the width of the component (routed page) manually or I'm doing something wrong?

I'm using Vuetify.js library (installed via npm)

I'm expecting this element `<p>some text here</p>` on the page **Home.vue** to take up 100% of the page's width (as normal), but it's not:

[image]

### CODE:

#### App.vue | router => Home.vue

```
   <!-- toolbar and drawer are here -->

    <main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </main>

  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      drawer: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Home.vue page

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>some text here</p>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: 'home',
  data () {
    return {
      snackbar: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a css issue, in `Home.vue` explicitly set the `div` width to be `100%` should work:

```
<css scoped>
div {
  width: 100%;
}
</css>
```

Comment: Thanks. So that's the way it should be, and I have to explicitly make every "page" component `width:100%` ? Doing it for the first time, it just surprised me to not see the default `display: block; width:100%`  html5 behavior in vue

Comment: Maybe you have other css settings at the `main` or `v-app` levels that have overwritten the default behavior. Not really sure, just a guess.

Comment: Well, it's not, perhaps Vuetify.js can be the reason to this. I'm not sure. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: I've updated the question, the reason to this was the tag `<main>` ... who would have thought